# How to format output in Test::Unit 2.5.x

Tags: ruby, testunit

We just moved from using the very first version of Test::Unit with the redgreen gem to Test::Unit 2.5.3 and the output is a bit screwed up.

I just want to get Test::Unit to output test results like RSpec, and it almost does, but for me, whenever a failure or error occurs, it outputs the results right at that spot, instead of aggregating all of them and outputting them at the end after the tests have all run.

The Redgreen gem doesn't appear to do anything in this case.

Is there a way to get this to be formatted the way I want?

Comment: When you say "failure or error", do you mean Test::Unit fails, or the app does?

Comment: Test failures and errors they look like ...F.....E.... but in my case the error message is spit out right after the F or E

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out after rummaging through the documentation.
You have to create a test-unit.yml and stick it in the root of your rails app with the following settings

```
runner: console
console_options:
  output_level: 2
  show_detail_immediately: false
```